# How to rename "Unlabeled Column #N"

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

I followed the SelectColumnsButton [documentation](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/SelectColumnsButton.html) and added an action column. I have the following code:

```
<DatagridConfigurable>
  <TextField source="id" />
  <TextField source="title" />
  <TextField source="author" />
  <TextField source="year" />
  <div> 
    // This column contains action buttons
  </div>
</DatagridConfigurable>
```

Why is the action button column called "Unlabeled Column #4" and how can I rename the column ?

I tried to add a label and a name to the div but nothing worked.

In other part of my app I have way bigger DatagridConfigurable with many custom columns, and it is not user friendly to have 10 columns called "Unlabeled Column #N".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [`<DatagridConfigurable>` doc](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Datagrid.html#configurable):

> The inspector uses the field `source` (or `label` when it’s a string) to display the column name. If you use non-field children (e.g. action buttons), then it’s your responsibility to wrap them in a component with a `label` prop, that will be used by the inspector

```
const FieldWrapper = ({ children, label }) => children;
const PostList = () => (
    <List>
        <DatagridConfigurable>
            <TextField source="id" />
            <TextField source="title" />
            <TextField source="author" />
            <TextField source="year" />
            <FieldWrapper label="Actions">
                <EditButton />
            </FieldWrapper>
        </DatagridConfigurable>
    </List>
);
```

Comment: Thanks. I think this should also be in the SelectColumnsButton documentation. Also for those trying this solution but not working, you should clear your local storage as react-admin saves in cache the column names.